# Java Getting different random numbers in different methods

Tags: java, graphics, random, actionlistener

So I'm working on this yahtzee game in java and I want to use these dices to show numbers 1-6.
My problem is that I get different "dice numbers" in different methods.

My random dice method:

```
public String roll(){
    int dice1 = (int )(Math.random() * 6 + 1),
            dice2 = (int )(Math.random() * 6 + 1),
            dice3 = (int )(Math.random() * 6 + 1),
            dice4 = (int )(Math.random() * 6 + 1),
            dice5 = (int )(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

    return dice1 +"   "+ dice2 +"   "+ dice3 +"   "+ dice4  +"   "+ dice5;
}
```

So I have this other action listener method. I've got a button for rolling the dices. Inside this method I want to have it so that when I press the button these random numbers get generated wo that I can use them in a paintComponent method. but when I try to do this I get different numbers in my actionListener method and in my paint component.

Here's my Action Listener:

```
roll.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){


            if(turn == true){

                roll();

                rolls++;
                start = false;
                updateUI();
                System.out.println( roll() );

            }
            if(rolls == 3){
                turn = false;
                System.out.println("Out of rolls");
            }

        }
    });
```

And my paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);



    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 2 - 25, getHeight() / 2 - 35, 12, 12, 0, 0);   //Dice 1
    g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 2 - 10, getHeight() / 2 - 35, 12, 12, 0, 0);   //Dice 2
    g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 2 + 5, getHeight() / 2 - 35, 12, 12, 0, 0);    //Dice 3
    g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 2 + 20, getHeight() / 2 - 35, 12, 12, 0, 0);    //Dice 4
    g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 2 + 35, getHeight() / 2 - 35, 12, 12, 0, 0);    //Dice 5



    if(start == false){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString( roll() , getWidth() / 2 - 25 , getHeight() / 2 - 25 );
    }


}
```

I basicly want to have the same numbers on the dices for all methods until I update them by pressing roll again.

Comment: To add on to Bathsheba, I would start with a Die class, which has a `roll` method and a `getValue`, which returns the last value generated by roll.  Then you could create a `Dice` class which contains a number of `Die`.  The `Dice` could roll all the `Die` and provide a simple `getValues` method that would return an array of values (from each `Die`).  Then it won't matter when you look at the values, because they won't change until you roll them.  It your current `actionPerformed` method, you seem to be ignoring the return value form your `roll` method any way

Comment: I think you should build a Dice object which has roll and fillRoundRect methods. (Better still, separate out the die data and its presentation components, but that's a topic all in itself). One die rolling is unrelated to another die rolling: as such I think your design is flawed. Do it the OO way and many of your problems will simply disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time you call roll() you are generating new random numbers, and so it will return differently. You need to store the result somewhere the first time you call roll() and only call it again when you want the dice to change.

Try the following changes.

In your class declaration:

```
private String rollResult = "";
```

In actionPerformed(...):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){


        if(turn == true){

            rollResult = roll();

            rolls++;
            start = false;
            updateUI();
            System.out.println( rollResult );

        }
```

In paintComponent(...):

```
if(start == false){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString( rollResult , getWidth() / 2 - 25 , getHeight() / 2 - 25 );
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help. While this works, it is still not the best way to do things. You should think about learning to approach things as suggested by MadProgrammer and Bathsheba above. It will make things much easier for you in the long run! Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
g.drawString( roll() , getWidth() / 2 - 25 , getHeight() / 2 - 25 );
```

the call in this method is an extra call, you recalculate the numbers because Math.random() is called again, so you just call the method also if you are repainting the jPanel